# Overlay an icon on the close tab button in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am developing a SDK addon. I want to implement a feature called Protect Tab. Right click a tab, an icon overlays on the close tab button, thereby lessen the chance of accidentally closing the tab.

A few Firefox addons already have this feature, such as Tabloc, Tab Utilities, etc. But these are XUL addons. What do I need to do to implement this feature?

[image: Overlay an icon on the close tab button]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy paste this code into scratchpad with browser environment and run it:

```
Cu.import('resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm');
var sss = Cc['@mozilla.org/content/style-sheet-service;1'].getService(Ci.nsIStyleSheetService);
try {
    sss.unregisterSheet(cssUri, sss.USER_SHEET);
} catch (ex) {}

var css = '';
/*css += '[anonid="close-button"] .toolbarbutton-icon:after { content:"rawr"; position:absolute; z-index:999999; width:10px; height:10px; background-color:red; }';*/ //i dont know why but i cant seem to put a before or after pseduo element on the image so i put it on the toolbar-button, if yo ucan figure this one out share with us
css += '[anonid="close-button"]:before { position:absolute; top:5px; background-color:black; width:20px; height:20px; content:""}';
css += '[anonid="close-button"] { pointer-events:none !important; }';
var cssEnc = encodeURIComponent(css);
    var newURIParam = {
        aURL: 'data:text/css,' + cssEnc,
        aOriginCharset: null,
        aBaseURI: null
}
var cssUri = Services.io.newURI(newURIParam.aURL, newURIParam.aOriginCharset, newURIParam.aBaseURI);
sss.loadAndRegisterSheet(cssUri, sss.USER_SHEET);
```

i overlay an image on top with pseudo element.

however you can just change the src of the image element, no need to overlay something on top of it

btw to prevent click on that close button you dont need to overlay anything you can just set the pointer-events to none like i did above.

Comment: When I used this code to overlay an icon on close tab button, close tab buttons on all tabs are overlayed with icon. I want to overlay icon on the active/current tab. Also, how do I undo the operation, ie, un-overlay, or remove the icon? Reverse the operation?

Thanks!

Comment: `[selected=true] [anonid="close-button"] {`

Comment: I forgot to mention, to un-overlay it, just unregister it, i do it at the top of the code: `sss.unregisterSheet(cssUri, sss.USER_SHEET);` so just run that bit again, `cssUri` must be global variable if you are running from another function.